# Generate RequireJS "bundles" config dynamically with Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, amd

1. According to the RequireJS API, the `bundles` configuration property is used to map modules to their bundle files (in production mode, assuming you have multiple bundles on large-scale projects).
2. I use Grunt for bundling with `r.js` of course, how can I generate the `bundle` configuration dynamically, according to the actual bundling? e.g. if module `angular` was bundled to `common.js`, then it should be added to the list of modules of the `common` bundle.

This part of requirejs configuration should not be maintained manually, as it will result in many mistakes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.2.0 of RequireJS introduced a [new optimizer option](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/67924d205978c917c78b02ad56fbc60ca6ce8183/build/example.build.js#L653) to write out a `bundles` option that is generated from the build:

```
//Introduced in 2.2.0. Path to file to write out bundles config
//(http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) found in the module
//layers built by the optimizer. The path is relative to the "dir" config's
//path. Only applies to full project optimization:
//http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject
//Only use if the optimized layers are grouped more intricately then just
//a simple optimization of main app entry points. The file path specified
//should be to one that has the top level requirejs.config() call that sets
//up the loader. If using "mainConfigFile", then this path likely should be
//the path to that file where it is placed in the "dir" output directory.
bundlesConfigOutFile: 'some/path/to/main.js',
```

If the option above does not work for you, then you'll have to do what I did and roll your own code to generate a proper value for `bundles`.

Comment: Do you know how requirejs generates the bundle config if you are using this option? Where does it get the links between the modules from?